# Using hidden elements for rich snippets for products

Tags: google, html, rich-snippets

I wanted to add rich snippets for my products pages. However, the information required in the elements are not particularly compatible with my current HTML. Is it ok to make the rich snippets all hidden display, so it doesn't effect my HTML?

Answer (score 3):

No. Serving up content only for the benefit of search engines is a major violation of their terms of services and will result in penalties for your site up to and including banning. You should refactor your HTML to be compatible with the rich snippets so you can take advantage of them without doing the exact opposite of what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: But for example my heading of the site is where I include the product name, but the heading contains other words other than just the product name, no where on the products page do I have just the product name. Ok perhaps I could have <h1>Buy <span id="snippet_element"><product name></span> Online</h1>
Would that be the way around it?

Comment: That sounds like a good solution to me

Answer (score 1):

Try using `schema.org` metadata for [Product](http://schema.org/Product).
If you want to add information that is not visible, you can use:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="YOUR_PRODUCT_NAME">
    <h1>Buy Online</h1>
</div>
```

Based on what I know, Google supports [this format](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158).